# Is it possible to add one point on billboard.js timeseries chart without providing an array of nulls?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, billboard.js

I'm trying to add some additional points on a timeseries chart.
I can do so by providing an extra data series, filled with null values for the first ticks.

What I'd like to know is if we can do something like the following:

- provide a value + timestamp for a data series, so only that point will be on the chart, without the need to fill it with null values.
  (e.g.: EXTRA: [400,"2013-01-03"])

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/billboard.js/dist/billboard.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/billboard.js/dist/billboard.pkgd.min.js"></script>
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="chart"></div>
  <script>
  bb.generate({
    bindto: "#chart",
    size: {
      width: 500,
      height: 250
    },
    data: {
      x: "x",
      columns: [
        ["x", "2013-01-01", "2013-01-02", "2013-01-03", "2013-01-04", "2013-01-05", "2013-01-06"],
        ["data1", 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
        ["data2", 130, 340, 200, 500, 250, 350],
        ["EXTRA", null, null, 400, null, null, null],
        ["EXTRA2", null, 410], //can omit the nulls after the value
      ]
    },
    axis: {
      x: {
        type: "timeseries",
        tick: {
          format: "%Y-%m-%d"
        }
      }
    },
  });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to load some data for specific x axis, you can do by `.load()` API.

The steps are:

- 1) Generate the chart as normal
- 2) Use `.load()` with the specified x axis data

  chart.load({
    columns: [
        ["x", "2013-01-03"],
        ["EXTRA", 400]
    ]
  });

> **NOTE:** There's a [bug not showing tooltip in correct x axis](https://github.com/naver/billboard.js/pull/519). This issue was already fixed and will be out in the next release. Meanwhile, you can use the fixed build with the [nightly build](https://github.com/naver/billboard.js/tree/nightly/dist).

Checkout the snippet for the demo:

```js
 var chart = bb.generate({
  bindto: "#chart",
  size: {
    width: 500,
    height: 250
  },
  data: {
    x: "x",
    columns: [
      ["x", "2013-01-01", "2013-01-02", "2013-01-03", "2013-01-04", "2013-01-05", "2013-01-06"],
      ["data1", 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
      ["data2", 130, 340, 200, 500, 250, 350]
    ]
  },
  axis: {
    x: {
      type: "timeseries",
      tick: {
        format: "%Y-%m-%d"
      }
    }
  },
});
  
chart.load({
  columns: [
   ["x", "2013-01-03"],
   ["EXTRA", 400]
  ]
});

chart.load({
  columns: [
   ["x", "2013-01-02"],
   ["EXTRA2", 410]
  ]
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/billboard.js/dist/billboard.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/billboard.js/dist/billboard.pkgd.min.js"></script>
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chart"></div>
</body>
</html>
```